# Renderer.OnBecameVisible for scenekit?

Tags: swift, scenekit

In Unity, there is an event (Rendered.OnBecameVisible) that you can subscribe to to know when an object (in SceneKit's parlance, an SCNNode) becomes visible "by any camera".

Does Scenekit have an equivalent method/functionality/event subscription/or anything remotely similar I can use to achieve the same-ish functionality? (calling a method when an SCNNode is "visible" by a camera)

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.OnBecameVisible.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no delegate method you could implement, but your [`SCNSceneRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer), typically your `SCNView`, has a `isNode(_:insideFrustumOf:)` method:

> Use this method to test whether a node lies within the viewing frustum defined by another node (which may or may not be the scene renderer’s current pointOfView node). For example, in a game scene containing multiple camera nodes, you could use this method to determine which camera is currently best for viewing a moving player character.

Comment: Worked like a freaking charm.